# Telegram python bot - Send a photo issue

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I'm struggling with telegram-python-bot. I'm trying to send an imagen when an action is triggered. The bot has a menu with some options, when the user selects one of them the bot replies with some text response. What i would like is to also send a picture along with the information.
What i did was:

```
def opciones(bot, update, context):
  
  query = bot.callback_query
  query.answer()
  
  if query.data == "option1":
    query.message.reply_text(text=option1_info(), parse_mode='html', quote=False)
    context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, photo=open(image_option1, 'rb'))
```

This replies with a "TypeError: opciones() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'"

I've also tried to add this after query.message.replytext.

```
requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + TOKEN + '/sendPhoto', files={'photo': (image_arcadyan, open(image_arcadyan,'rb'))}, data= {'chat_id': chatId})
```

This works but only for a chat_id in particular, i cannot update the chat_id for every person or group that asks for it, I've tried using chat_id=update.effective_chat.id but had issues with update parameter.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TypeError: opciones() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'
```

You get this exception because in `python-telegram-bot` (v12+) handler callbacks must accept exactly two positional arguments of type `telegram.Update` and `telegram.ext.CallbackContext.` I.e. your function signature should read

```
def opciones(update, context):
    ...
```

where `update` is an instance of `telegram.Update` and `context` is an instance of `telegram.ext.CallbackContext`.

Note that the `Bot` instance is available as `context.bot`. See the docs of [`CallbackContext`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.callbackcontext.html) for more info on that object and the [tutorial](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot) for a general introduction into PTB.

If you change the signature and change `query = bot.callback_query` to `query = update.callback_query`, the rest of your snippet looks okay.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting this error now: ```query.message.reply_text(text=option1_info(), parse_mode='html', quote=False)
TypeError:option1_info() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'update' and 'context'
```

Comment: Well, apparently that function is defined as `def option1_info(update, context):`. So you either need to pass those arguments or change the definition of the function. But this is really Python 101 …